# jQuery function being called incorrectly.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a slider in my code. when I click I click on it, it alerts a message "called". But the problem here is it is alerting the message only when the square on the slider is clicked but I want to alert a message after clicking anywhere on the slider.

Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function () {

         $("#slider-1").slider({
             range: true,
             min: 0,
             max: 500,
             values: [0, 0],
             slide: function (event, ui) {
                 $("#priceA").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
             },
             stop: function () {
                 getValues();
             }
         });


     });

$("#slider-1").click(function(){
alert('Called');
});      

});          
</script>
</head>
<p>
    <label for="priceA">Price rangeA:</label>
    <input type="text" id="priceA" style="border:0; color:#067ab4; font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<div id="slider-1" class="myClass"></div><br><br>
</html>
```

Comment: what is `the square on the slider`? Can you add a jsfiddle.net demo?

Comment: @sabithpocker this is his [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/auE27/) that I have created. I hope he wants to get the `Price Range`

Comment: Hey, Please mark the answer accepted (as you mentioned it did work for you.) thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want that even clicking randomly on the slider should alert a message:: then try this:

```
stop: function () {
  alert('called');
  getValues();
}
```

and here is  [DEMO LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/auE27/1/) , check it out.